# Get average of data every 15 minutes

Tags: excel, formula, average

[image: Datalog]

I want to get my **Average Speed** every *15 minutes*. The interval that the log is collecting can vary so I can not expect the same number of rows every 15 minutes. **I am trying to keep this to a formula**, *but can use VBA if needed*.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @AjGootee! Can you please show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Im not good enough in Excel or math to have my own idea's, but I was trying to make something work I found on another site: =IF(CEILING(B2+TIME(0,0,1),TIME(0,15,0))=CEILING(B3+TIME(0,0,1),TIME(0,15,0)),"",AVERAGEIF(B$2:B2,">="&FLOOR(B2+TIME(0,0,1),TIME(0,15,0)),E$2:E2)). The problem is it gives a DIV error and I cant figure out why, the explanation is  dividing by 0 or an empty cell but neither is the case.

Comment: I guess that the idea would be to flag each row depending on its time (column B) so that you can average on this criterium. does the series always begin with hh:01?

Comment: No, can start at any time and collect at changing intervals.